# MS Edge reserves to much space for image

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, microsoft-edge

I'm getting a strange behavior in Microsoft Edge for my footer.
I have extracted the problem into a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o3eroydw/3/) so it's easier to help.

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div class="slide-footer">
        <div class="slide-icon active">
          <img src="..." />
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have a footer which is positioned via flex-box to always stick at the bottom.
inside of that footer there is another flex-box which is basically used for centering of the footer-elements.

The elements inside the footer have an image inside which takes 80% of the footers height and are therefore resized.
In chrome / firefox the footer-element takes only the space which the **resized** image needs but in edge the element takes as much width as the original image would need and therefore breaks the layout.

Note: this does not happen all the time so here is an screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're right that the behavior comes and goes. I thought I had it fixed, and now it's working fine with no adjustments. Anyway, this may help you: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/891815